# How can we implement scope for style tag using Javascript

Tags: html

I have a style tag defined in Head

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            p
            {
                font-size:10pt;
                color:green;
            }
            div
            {
                font-size:16pt;
                color:blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="div1">
            <p> hello p in div1 </p>
            <div> hello div in div1 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="div2">
            <p> hello p in div2 </p>
            <div> hello div in div2 </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here i want to add the style tag scope only to the div2. 
div1 should not get any of the styles mentioned in the style tag.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried already

Comment: Change `div {}` to `.div2 {}` in your style?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a class selector `.` in your css to specify what you want to style. For example, if you only want to style the second div that has class `div2`, that can be written as `.div2`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .div2 p
            {
                font-size:10pt;
                color:green;
            }
            .div2 div
            {
                font-size:16pt;
                color:blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="div1">
            <p> hello p in div1 </p>
            <div> hello div in div1 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="div2">
            <p> hello p in div2 </p>
            <div> hello div in div2 </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`.div2 p` means `apply this style to p elements within any element with the div2 tag`

`.div2 div` means `apply this style to div elements within any element with the div2 tag`

now, if you want to be more specific, you can use `div.div2 p`, and `div.div2 div`, which means p and div elements within a div with the div2 tag, respectively.

Comment: Yeah i understood this... but i have a problem, i will not be sure how exactly this style tag will be. I have received this from another application and i will be adding to my HTML head tag. So i wanted to prevent it from getting applied to specific html elements say the div with class name div1, and at same time, it should get applied to other HTML elements.

Comment: @VeenaSujith so are you saying that using your current style, you want a way to not apply those styles to, for example .div1? if so, you'll need to either overwrite those styles with another stylesheet, or use inline styling on div1

Comment: yes.. that is exactly what is want. I tried overwriting using another style sheet. But since which all styles need to be reseted is not sure as the current style sheet is shared by some other application is catch point. I tried with resetting all the styles which is creating many side effects in my application. That is why i was searching a solution for blocking the styles from getting applied to .div1.

Comment: @VeenaSujith if .div1 is the only thing you're worried about, just overwrite the style for only .div1

Answer (score 0):

Use the class given to the elements that makes it very specific.

```css
.div2 p {
    font-size:10pt;
    color:green;
}

.div2 div {
    font-size:16pt;
    color:blue;
}
```

It will only set the style for second `div`. Try this

Comment: i have already tried this and i understood it works, but in my case i am not sure how exactly the style tag will be as i received it from another application. so for adding class name to each of the tag need parsing of the whole data. is there any better way to achieve this.